# How to get all linked element id's on jointjs?

Tags: jointjs

I am trying to identify sequenced elements on jointjs, is there any methods to get all elements that are sequenced together? For example i am trying to identify which elements are sequence so that can be grouped together in the below diagram. 
[image]

Comment: Post the data you have, and the things you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Sequenced elements can be found either through traversing:

1. from the sources ([`graph.getSources()`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getSources) roots/parents)

   - to the successors ([`graph.getSuccessors(element [, opt])`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getSuccessors) children):

     ```
     var rootsIdsSequence = {};
     graph.getSources().forEach(function (el) {
       var children = graph.getSuccessors(el);
       if(children && children.length !== 0)
         rootsIdsSequence[el.id] = children;
     })
     ```
2. or from the sinks ([`graph.getSinks()`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Graph.prototype.getSinks) last children/leaves)

   - to the sources ([`element.getAncestors()`](https://resources.jointjs.com/docs/jointjs/v2.0/joint.html#dia.Element.prototype.getAncestors) roots/parents):

     ```
     var childrenIdsSequence = {};
     graph.getSinks().forEach(function (el) {
       var roots = el.getAncestors();
       if(roots && roots.length !== 0)
         childrenIdsSequence[el.id] = roots;
     })
     ```

I suggest the first option, since you may have less sources/roots than sinks/leaves and sometimes `el.getAncestors()` may return empty even when there's a link connected to the element.